# How to turn off physical keyboard through adb command?

Tags: android, adb

[image]

I want to turn off it through adb in android. But I can not find the right command.
I have tried to search sqlite in providers.settings but found nothing.
Is there anyone knows the right command?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Sorry, found nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InputMethodManager.setInputMethodEnabled(String id, boolean enabled)` to do what you want. First you need to find the full input method ID for your keyboard - most likely you would be able to find it in the `dumpsys input_method` output.
Then you can use `service call input_method 28 s16 'input.method.name' i32 0` do disable and `service call input_method 28 s16 'input.method.name' i32 1` to re-enable the input method.

The following command has added `Google Hindi Input` on an Android 5.1 phone:

```
adb shell su 0 service call input_method 28 s16 'com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi/.HindiInputMethodService' i32 1`
```

And this command has removed it from the list of enabled input methods:

```
adb shell su 0 service call input_method 28 s16 'com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi/.HindiInputMethodService' i32 0`
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it can not turn off the physical keyboard.